# Updating row in table in android using execSQL statement

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to update the row in database table but its not updating due to some below mentioned problems. Please Help ! 
This is the logcat error.

04-23 02:34:56.435: D/PackageItemInfo(27696): loadIcon(cached)name=org.example.beproj.MainActivity
04-23 02:35:06.576: D/dalvikvm(27696): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 418K, 40% free 10126K/16688K, paused 18ms, total 26ms
04-23 02:35:06.596: I/dalvikvm-heap(27696): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.996MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-23 02:35:06.616: D/dalvikvm(27696): GC_CONCURRENT freed 23K, 27% free 18202K/24792K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 22ms
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/SQLiteLog(27696): (1) no such column: ID
04-23 02:35:16.797: D/AndroidRuntime(27696): Shutting down VM
04-23 02:35:16.797: W/dalvikvm(27696): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41276ae0)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE vgs SET Steps = 'xguvdyij' WHERE ID = 0
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:888)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:499)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at org.example.beproj.update_final$2.onClick(update_final.java:92)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4278)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17429)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And the code is

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
new_text=editText1.getText().toString();
String update = "UPDATE "+table_name+" SET Steps = '"+ new_text +"' WHERE ID = " + position;
db.execSQL(update);
```

Comment: i have also used this code but its not getting updated

Comment: ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("Steps", new_text);
String where="_id ="+position;
db.update(table_name, newValues,"_id="+position, null);

Comment: `no such column: ID` check your database with a editor if it contains the necessary columns.

Comment: ya Sorry instead of ID it has to be _id but still the contents are not updated :(

Comment: yes i got it .. position was not specified properly! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error specifies the problem:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-23 02:35:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(27696): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE vgs SET Steps = 'xguvdyij' WHERE ID = 0
```